# Read line by line a text selection

Tags: java

I need to implement a toggle comment for my own editor but i don't know how to read a `ITextSelection` line by line to add "//" at the beginning of the line.

I have already the `ITextSelection` and the IDocument of the text editor and I have tried to use a BufferedReader but I don't know how to get the path of the current document...

```
ITextSelection sel = (ITextSelection) getTextEditor().getSelectionProvider().getSelection();
IDocument doc = getTextEditor().getDocumentProvider().getDocument(getTextEditor().getEditorInput());
```

and

```
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("?"));
```

Comment: What is an `ITextSelection`?

Comment: @Henry maybe https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.eclipse.jface.text.ITextSelection

Comment: Edit : I found the file document name but when i try this i catch a file not found exception : azdaz.dxl (The system cannot find the file specified) : BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getTextEditor().getEditorInput().getName()));

Comment: @Henry This interface represents a textual selection. A text selection is a range ofcharacters. Although a text selection is a snapshot taken at a particularpoint in time, it must not copy the line information and the selected textfrom the selection provider.